# how to hide popup alert in chamilo footer

Tags: chamilo-lms

someone in good faith can help. I'm trying to use chamilo. how to hide the alerts that always appear in the footer chamilo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEoah.png)

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to hide it? It gives you information about professional support, only appears on the main admin page (only for admins) *and* gets hidden when you click the "x" icon :-)

Anyway... you can disable it by adding this to the end of your app/config/configuration.php file:

```
$_configuration['admin_chamilo_announcements_disable'] = true;
```

Comment: Please don't forget contributing back to the Chamilo project. We work hard to get you free software to improve education. Wanting to hide this banner suggests you are probably trying to hide the origin of the software to third parties, while our project could really use extra contributions.